# how to save downloaded image in perticular directory in ubuntu with python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm downloading images from the url and currently it's being saved in current directory. I want to save that image in any particular directory. Please help me out how to do that.

```
url= https://example.com
name = myImage
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,name+".jpeg")
```

or

```
response = requests.get(url)
file = open(name+".jpeg", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

Both the above code is working fine but images are being saved in current directory.

Comment: You're opening the faile `name + ".jpeg"` in the current directory. You should specify the whole path to the file. Either relative `"./dir1/dir2/" + name + ".jpeg"`or absolute `"/home/dir1/dir2/ + name + ".jpeg"`

Answer (score 1):

you can provide path to the directory in which you want to save image and append before the image name.

```
url= https://example.com
name = myImage
dir_to_save_file = '/home/dir1/dir2/'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,dir_to_save_file+name+".jpeg")
```

or

```
response = requests.get(url)
dir_to_save_file = '/home/dir1/dir2/' 
file = open(dir_to_save_file + name+".jpeg", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```